# WinRT API in .Net 4.5

Tags: .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I am trying to use

```
Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI()  of Metro Style app
```

in WPF application in VS11. Now I know there are others library for doing camera capture, but It is possible to use a API of Metro Style App in normal WPF appliaction. Can i add refrence to  these libraries of Metro Style App to it externally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN should have documentation of which winrt APIs work from desktop apps. I don't believe any of the media APIs fall into that category